# Performance penalties on using "this->"?

Tags: c++

Consider this example of two similar C++ member functions in a class C:

```
void C::function(Foo new_f) {
    f = new_f;
}
```

and

```
void C::function(Foo new_f) {
    this->f = new_f;
}
```

Are these functions compiled in the same manner? Are there any performance penalties for using `this->` (more memory accesses or whatever)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's exactly the same and you'll get the same performance.

The only time you really *must* use the `this->` syntax is when you have an argument to the function with the same name as an instance variable you want to access. Using the name of the variable by itself will refer to the argument so you need the `this->`. Of course, you could just rename the argument too. And, as ildjarn has pointed out in the comments also, you need to use `this` in certain situations to call functions that are dependent because `this` is implicitly dependent (you can read more about that though).

Comment: There are other contexts where `this->` is needed, e.g. inside of class template member functions when accessing base class members.

Comment: @ildjarn I did not know that, do you know where I can read about it?

Comment: [This FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/templates.html#faq-35.19) scratches the surface, but it's described in detail in Sutter's Exceptional C++ series.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie -- read about two phase lookup, you need this-> to make a name dependent and delay lookup to the point of instantiation.

Comment: what it boils down to is that templates bind names when the template is defined -- because if the binding was deferred there'd be no control over what names refer to. COnsidering "int a; template<typename T>struct x{int a; x(): a(0){}};
template<typename T>struct y:x<T>{void foo(){++a;}};
int main(int,char**) {
  a=5; y<int> yy = {}; yy.foo(); return a;
}", think about what happens if you move the definitions around, or decide to specialize x<int>.

Comment: You can always insert a `using base_template<x,y,z>::inherited_member;` declaration into the class template though, which eliminates the need for `this->` for that member. This is a good practice for members that will be used often. You might argue it's a good idea for members that will be used even once, since it makes the template interface explicit, which is a weak point of C++.

Comment: Yes the purpose of my question was to decide what coding style to use: i like to write function arguments with the same name of instance variables and use this-> to distinguish them.

Comment: @integeruser : Anyone else who reads your code is going to hate you for that. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn really? i'd use this notation only on simple setters like "this->x = x;". I don't find that confusing..and most of all i suck to find variable names that i like, so this alleviates the problem :)

Comment: @integeruser : Ambiguity requires a higher level of effort to understand.

Answer (score 3):

From the viewpoint of the compiler, there's no difference between `this->` being implicit and being explicit.

Remember, however, that code should be written primarily for human readers, and only secondarily for the compiler. From this viewpoint, using `this->` (except in the few places it's truly needed) is a huge loss, and should be expunged from all code.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "is a huge loss"

Comment: @Scottymac : It's extraneous noise, pointlessly cluttering the code and effectively making it harder to read.

Comment: I rarely use `this->` ... but I don't see it as such a horrible thing... "huge loss" seems a bit of an exaggeration... there are times that explicitness and clarity it provides is essential for easy code reading...

Comment: @Scottymac: I've yet to see a single time or circumstance in which I thought it improved clarity. It's sometimes a necessary evil, but if it's not necessary, just evil.

Comment: you call it evil... I call it unnecessary... potato/potato "chacun à son goût"

Comment: I like to write function arguments with the same name of instance variables and use this-> to distinguish them. In this example i've called the argument "new_f" instead of "f" just for clarity: my real code was void C::function(Foo f) {this->f = f;}

Answer (score 2):

It's a shorthand. In this case, it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance penalty for the resulting code, because the compiler will have to use `this` to access the member anyway.

There *is* a performance penalty for me reading the code, because I would have to stop here and think "Why is `this->` needed here? Is there a coding trick involved? Did I just miss something important about this class? Or did the coder just insert a random `this->` for no reason?".

Comment: Sorry no coding trick involved, i was just curious about compiler behaviour. Also, for setter methods i like to write function arguments with the same name of instance variables and use this-> to distinguish them. And because there are no penalties i will continue to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler uses this pointer for you without you even knowing it. Whenever you type it yourself, you're explicitly stating it, but there's (in some cases) no need.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the assembly output of the two functions by compiling them under GCC with the flag -S. This will generate symbolic assembly code for the input C/C++ files, and the two should be identical.