# Difference when assigning values to class data members using self pointer

Tags: c++, oop, class, pointers

Suppose I have a class like:

```
Class MyClass 
{ 
  int myVar1;
  int myVar2;

  void myMethod(); 
}
```

is there any difference in the two value assignments below ?

```
void MyClass::myMethod()
{
   //VARIABLE ASSIGNMENT
   myVar1 = 99;

   //USING POINTER TO CLASS
   this->myVar2 = 99;
}
```

What's the use of the

> this->

pointer in variables' assignment (except other cases when eg. passing the class via a function etc.) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performance penalties on using "this->"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559718/performance-penalties-on-using-this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the same thing, unless you happen to have two variables with the same name in the scope. In that case you can differentiate using this->.

Answer (score 4):

It makes a difference in the following situation:

```
void MyClass::myMethod(int myVar1)
{
   myVar1 = 99; //doesn't change the member

   this->myVar1 = 99; //changes the member
}
```

In your case, no difference.

Comment: could you please explain your example with some inline values of myVar1 ? (after myMethod has been called with a parameter for myVar1 what's the value after the first assignment ? what after the second? THANKS !

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference.  Sometimes using `this->` aids in disambiguation, but not here.